# How to calculate Day total as well as Monthly Total in the same Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get day total of Petty Cash (I'm already getting this) & need Monthly total relevant to Account Codes for today. Following I'm showing SQL for daily total. Someone Please help me to Calculate Monthly totals in the same row.

```
SELECT DPetAcNo as AcNo,
   SUM(DPetAmount) as DayTotal
   FROM PettyDetail
   WHERE DPetComCode='15'
         and DPetLocCode='01'
         and DPetDate=CONVERT(date,'20181113',111)
         GROUP BY DPetAcNo
```

---

Result for the above query show below

[image: Result]

According to the result 2018/11/13 AcNo 009111 Total = 22,995.00
and actual cumulative (2018/11/01 - 2018/11/13) total for 009111 = 136,265.42

[image: Cumulative total]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified version of regbas’ answer that should perform better because it doesn’t consider so many rows:

```
SELECT DPetAcNo as AcNo,
   SUM(case when DPetDate=CONVERT(date,'20181113',111) then DPetAmount else 0 end) as DayTotal,
   SUM(DPetAmount) as MonthTotal
   FROM PettyDetail
   WHERE DPetComCode='15'
         and DPetLocCode='01'
         and DPetDate >= '2018-11-01'
         AND DPetDate < '2018-12-01'
         AND DPetAcNo IN (select dpetacno from pettydetail WHERE DPetComCode='15'
         and DPetLocCode='01'
         and DPetDate = '2018-11-13')
         GROUP BY DPetAcNo
```

Sqlserver will implicitly convert a ‘yyyy-mm-dd’ string to a date if you want to skip the CONVERT code clutter. Having an index that covers date, comcode, loccode, account and includes amount will also help

——

Another way to approach this is to use the queries you seem to have already written for daytotal and cumtotal, like this:

```
Select * from
(/*Insert your query that does daytotal into these brackets*/) d
Inner join
(/*Insert your query that does cumtotal into these brackets*/) c
ON d.DPetAcNo = c.dpetacno
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DPetAcNo as AcNo,
   SUM(case when DPetDate=CONVERT(date,'20181113',111) then DPetAmount else 0 end) as DayTotal,
   SUM(case when month(DPetDate)= 11 then DPetAmount else 0 end) as MonthTotal
   FROM PettyDetail
   WHERE DPetComCode='15'
         and DPetLocCode='01'
         GROUP BY DPetAcNo
```

Comment: Dear RegBes, Yes I got the result. But I need only monthly total relevant to TODAY'S DPetAcNo only. Your solution calculate all table DPetAcNo relevant to the month of November.

Comment: @mark in fairness to regbas, 3 separate professionals all misinterpreted the question in the same way, so it possibly wasn’t a clear requirement.. check the updated answers (mine and squirrel) to address the requirements

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your DPetDate is a Date or Datetime data type.

You will need to filter the rows for the 1st of the month to the required date. 
for both day & month total on the same result, use `CASE` in the `SUM ()`

```
SELECT DPetAcNo as AcNo,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DPetDate  = '20181113' THEN DPetAmount ELSE 0 END) as DayTotal,
   SUM(DPetAmount) as MonthTotal,
   FROM PettyDetail
   WHERE DPetComCode='15'
         and DPetLocCode='01'
         and DPetDate >= '20181101'   -- from 1st of Nov
         and DPetDate <= '20181113'   -- to   13  of Nov
         GROUP BY DPetAcNo
```

EDIT 1:
to only select AccNo based on the required date. Using subquery to get the Month Total. Or alternatively you can do it in a `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT  *,
       ( SELECT SUM(DPetAmount) 
         FROM   PettyDetail x 
         WHERE  x.DPetAcNo = p.AcNo 
         AND    x.DPetComCode = '15' 
         AND    x.DPetLocCode = '01'
         AND    x.DPetDate >= '20180101' 
         AND    x.DPetDate <= '20181113') as MonthTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT DPetAcNo as AcNo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DPetDate  = '20181113' THEN DPetAmount ELSE 0 END) as DayTotal
       FROM PettyDetail p
       WHERE DPetComCode='15'
             and DPetLocCode='01'
             and DPetDate = '20181113'   -- for 13  of Nov only
             GROUP BY DPetAcNo
) p
```

Comment: “Great minds think alike.. ..and fools seldom differ!” :)

Comment: Dear Squirrel, Thank you for your reply. Your result shows non today AcNo totals also. I need only today total as well as cumulative total for the relevant AcNo. Not for other AcNos

Comment: Euww.. Putting a correlated query in a select block? Never would have expected you to do that!

Comment: either that or a `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: I need to wash my eyes :)

Comment: Thank You. Solution fit for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about a self join ?

```
SELECT 
    DPetAcNo AcNo
,   DayTotal
,   SUM(DPetAmount) MonthlyTotal
FROM PettyDetail pd
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DPetAcNo AcNo
    ,   SUM(DPetAmount) DayTotal
    FROM 
        PettyDetail
    WHERE 
        DPetComCode='15'
    AND DPetLocCode='01'
    AND DPetDate = CONVERT(DATE,'20181113',111)
    GROUP BY DPetAcNo
) pd2 ON pd2.AcNo = dp.DPetAcNo
WHERE 
    MONTH(DPetDate) = MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,'20181113',111)) 
AND YEAR(DPetDate)  = YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,'20181113',111))
GROUP BY DPetAcNo, DayTotal
```

Comment: Dear iSR5, your solution creates only AcNo and MonthlyTotal only. No DayTotal creates.

Comment: @Mark fixed, check now.